# Windows 8 push notification com PHP

Tags: php, windows, push-notification

Queria um exemplo bem simples de como são feitas as notificações do windows 8 ou 7 com PHP.

Comment: Acredito que o mais próximo que de pra fazer sejam notificações através do Chrome e não do Windows.